# Skype way too quiet. How to get louder Skype audio output on my MacBook Pro?

Tags: itunes, audio, skype, speakers, sound-volume

My girlfriend and I are getting really irritated with how quiet Skype is on my new MacBook Pro.  Even with the volume turned up to the max, I can still barely hear her even with my air conditioning and fan off.

At first, I thought about buying a pair of speakers, but even the small USB ones would be irritating to have to have around all the time.  Then I thought of buying a new sound card, but then I realized that iTunes with the preamp in the equalizer set to 12 is actually more than loud enough.

Is there a way that I could connect to that and make Skype that loud?  Or is there any other way to make it louder?

On a smaller note, I've been having the same issue with movies played in Google Chrome.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your speakers, in my opinion.

Comment: Have you and your girlfriend tried checking your microphone volume levels. It could  be the case the her mic is turned down too low and that is causing you to have to turn up your sound to the maximum.

Comment: If you're boosting the frequencies levels across the board just to hear iTunes than something is wrong. Your hearing, or expectations are outside of the *normal range, the MBP is misconfigured, or there is a genuine defect with the hardware. Regardless, I don't think you're looking for a fix for *Skype*, I think you need to search for the root cause.

Comment: Her microphone is turned up really loud, and like I said iTunes is nice and loud.  It's not, like inaudible when the equalizer isn't used, in fact I can hear it pretty well then too.  Whatever it is, there must be some way I can give Skype and Chrome more volume.  I don't think it's a problem with the MacBook because I've seen a lot of similar issues on Google.

Comment: How are the levels if you plug in a headset? Is there still a major discrepancy between *Skype* volume and *iTunes*?

Comment: Yes, although I can hear it (everything is louder in my headphones).

Comment: Have you tried Skyping with someone else - anyone else (including the Skype test call) to see if that was sufficiently loud?  Has she tried Skyping with anyone else (or with you on a different machine) to see whether they could hear her?

Comment: Yeah, the others are a little louder, but still not loud enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [Boom system-wide volume booster tool](http://www.globaldelight.com/boom/).  While it's not free, it is cheap: $6.99. See reviews [here](http://www.softpedia.com/reviews/mac/Boom-Review-186783.shtml), [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1157259/boomexpo.html), and [here](http://www.macworld.com/article/1160402/boom1.html).  Below is the description from the product page, and a screenshot:

> Boom is a simple volume booster and system-wide equalizer that lets
>   you boost the volume of your Mac and your music files.
>
> Using Boom is simple. You know the ways to change the volume of your
>   Mac. Boom provides the same easy access to boost sound.
>
> From the videos on YouTube, Hulu, your favorite music playing on
>   iTunes, **to voice applications like Skype**, iChat and your favorite
>   Games, Boom can boost them all. [...]

*(emphasis above is mine)*

[image: Boom screenshot]

I use Boom on my own MacBook Air and it does a reasonable job of increasing the internal speaker volume beyond what I was getting with the built-in volume controls at maximum.  The graphic equalizer is an added bonus, letting me tweak the sound I get from these tiny speakers so it sounds a bit better for music.

Comment: All well and good, but is there a way to do this for free?

Comment: Free? Other than learning how to code such a tool yourself, not that I know of.  FWIW, this is not a new problem; see http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=107727 and http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=407612 .. Free hasn't crashed the party yet.

Comment: @AndrewLatham: you can get this app in a discounted bundle for the next day from [MacUpdate](https://www.mupromo.com/appbundle.php) ($50), which includes 10 other applications.

Answer (score 9):

Did you check the settings in the app "Audio MIDI Setup"?
It's in /Applications/Utilities.
Sometimes the settings there can get out of whack.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I did, there wasn't anything different.

Comment: I love you. No idea why it was suddenly *that quiet*, but changing the settings here helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check your overall sound mixer settings? You can adjust this so that Skype is the loudest thing playing on your computer.

Comment: Could you be a little more specific on how to get to the sound mixer settings, and how to adjust them?

Answer (score -1):

In Skype itself, there is a whole bunch of settings called (i don't know the exact english term for them) call/chatquality-quidelines, they are found when clicking on the bars, looking like Wifi-signal. These bars are signals from Skype telling you something about some problems with microphone, speakers and webcam. If you click on these bars, a window posp out, having some tabs there like microphone and speakers. On both, you can adjust the volume skype-internally, both microphone and speakers have a checkbox for automatic adjustment and a manual adjustment bar. try to set them both to manual and maximum on both participating computers.
Since this is mostly out of memory, excuse me for being incorrect! Someone has to find the right english terms...