# Is there free utility to amplify the system volume?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, sound-volume

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do you know a simple sound booster app for Mac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/793/do-you-know-a-simple-sound-booster-app-for-mac)
>   [Skype way too quiet. How to get louder Skype audio output on my MacBook Pro?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/45700/skype-way-too-quiet-how-to-get-louder-skype-audio-output-on-my-macbook-pro)

I came across [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8311/amplify-sound-output-on-mac) about tools that amplify sound in OS X, but they're not free.

Are you aware of a free tool that boosts the volume?

Comment: @daviesgeek there aren't any editable settings in Audio Midi Setup.

Comment: Making Skype louder is a very different question than making all system volume louder. Not a duplicate. Even if some of the answers answer both questions, that doesn't make the question a duplicate. Otherwise, every question that could be answered "reboot your computer" would be a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy to get your hands dirty and you're a registered Apple Developer, you could use [Soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/) to pipe your system audio into AU Lab (search for AU Lab on the ADC [Downloads page](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/)) and push everything through Apple's own awful AUDynamicsProcessor Audio Unit.

Comment: hmm, well then, why not just plug the system's audio output into an audio amplifier. I have my system piped to my stereo system. I can regulate sound through the receiver.

Comment: The only reason I can concieve of that you would want to boost system volume is that you're on the build-in speakers (or some little passive speakers) and the only volume control you have — the system-level one — does not go high enough. If post-system amplification was an option, this question would not have been asked.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features). The link is to the features page. The app is hosted on [Sourceforge](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/download/mac). (download link).

Comment: Audacity can amplify individual audio files but would be useless for amping up system audio.